# How to get the return value of a child process in C after parent process ends?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm new so bear with me. I compiled an exe from a c file which uses fork(). I have the parent process return a value, let's say "A," and the child process returns "B." When the program ends and I "echo $?" the last return, I get "A."

I do have waitpid() implemented for the child to finish. But is there a way to output "B"(whatever that value is) from the shell after the process has finished?

Comment: "A" has to forward B's return code to the shell. "A" can get B's return code from the status information that `waitpid` provides.

Comment: @user3386109 So after the process ends, is there a simple command to run to get B's return value?